# Magento 2: discount coupon not working ONLY on checkout page

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon

In Magento 2.3.3 and I have noticed that the discount code is not working on the Checkout Page.

The weird thing is that, It is working on the Cart Page, but on the Checkout Page It doesn't do anything.

On top of that, **the buttons don't even have any text**. In order to click on the right button, I have checked using inspect the element in order to check which one is the Cancel and which one is the Apply button.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

How can I fix it? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here, any news?

Comment: It was a problem of the theme I was using. They took care of that.